# Vibrate-before-ring

Tags: ringtone, vibration

Is there a way to have an android phone vibrate first before it starts ringing?

Note that I'm looking for a clean solution, i.e. I don't want to modify the ringtone to include a few seconds of silence at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard good things about [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm). I wonder if it can help?